# Missing data in R - How to skip grouping of days with missing information?

Tags: r, date, missing-data

I have hourly values of temperature measurements and I wish to calculate the average per day only for complete (i.e. with 24 measurements) days. Incomplete days would then be summarized as "NA".

I have grouped the values together per year, month and day and call summarize().
I have three month of data missing which appears as a gap in my ggplot function and which is what I want to achieve with the rest. The problem is that when I call `summarize()` to calculate the mean of my values, days with only 1 or 2 measurements also get called. Only those with all missing values (24) appear as "NA".

```
                   Date TempUrb  TempRur       UHI
1   2011-03-21 22:00:00    10.1 11.67000 -1.570000
2   2011-03-21 23:00:00     9.9 11.67000 -1.770000
3   2011-03-22 00:00:00    10.9 11.11000 -0.210000
4   2011-03-22 01:00:00    10.7 10.56000  0.140000
5   2011-03-22 02:00:00     9.7 10.00000 -0.300000
6   2011-03-22 03:00:00     9.5 10.00000 -0.500000
7   2011-03-22 04:00:00     9.4  8.89000  0.510000
8   2011-03-22 05:00:00     8.4  8.33500  0.065000
9   2011-03-22 06:00:00     8.2  7.50000  0.700000

AvgUHI <- UHI %>%  group_by(year(Date), add = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(month(Date), add = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(day(Date), add = TRUE, .drop = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(AvgUHI = mean(UHI, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 2,844 x 4
# Groups:   year(Date), month(Date) [95]

   `year(Date)` `month(Date)` `day(Date)`  AvgUHI
        <int>         <int>       <int>   <dbl>
1476    2015             4       4     0.96625000
1477    2015             4       5     -0.11909722
1478    2015             4       6     -0.60416667
1479    2015             4       7     -0.92916667
1480    2015             4       8     NA
1481    2015             4       9     NA

AvgUHI<- AvgUHI %>%  group_by(`year(Date)`, add = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(`month(Date)`, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(AvgUHI= mean(AvgUHI, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 95 x 3
# Groups:   year(Date) [9]
   `year(Date)` `month(Date)`  AvgUHI
          <int>         <int>   <dbl>
 50        2015             4   0.580887346 
 51        2015             5   0.453815051
 52        2015             6   0.008479618
```

As you can see above on the final table, I have an average for 04-2015, while I am missing data on that month (08 - 09/04/2015 on this example represented on the second table). 
The same happens when I calculate AvgUHI and I'm missing hourly data.

I simply would like to see on the last table the AvgUHI for 04-2015 be NA.

E.g: of my graph[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0jXq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give a dataframe aggregated by day, where only the complete days, with 4 observations, are not `NA`. Then you can group by month to have the final dataframe.

```
UHI %>%
  mutate(Day = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  mutate(n = n(), tmpUHI = if_else(n == 24, UHI, NA_real_)) %>%
  summarize(AvgUHI = mean(tmpUHI)) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(Day = seq(min(.$Day), max(.$Day), by = "day"))) %>%
  arrange(Day) -> AvgUHI
```

Comment: Yes this worked great for hours thanks. It did not work for months though. I'll write the in the answers section

Comment: I do not understand the full_join() function that you use at the end. What does this add to the code?

Comment: @FrancoGrosso it adds the `NA` values even if there are no values in a full month, if a month (or more) is completely missing.

Answer (score 0):

For hours look at Rui Barradas' answer. For months the following code worked:

```
AvgUHI %>%
  group_by(year(Day), add = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(month(Day), add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(is.na(AvgUHI)), tmpUHI = if_else(sum <= 10, AvgUHI, NA_real_)) %>%
  summarise(AvgUHI = mean(tmpUHI, na.rm = TRUE)) -> AvgUHI
```